# How can I limit Bootstrap column to a specific column's height?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Making bootstrap's column the same height has already been answered here:

[How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

However I have a bit of a different requirement.

Specifically, I need a column's height to be limited to the height of a specific column.

For example, if we have 2 columns `(100px, 50px)` respectively, I want my first column to have height of `50px` too which I'm going to be using (`overflow:hidden`) in. (Note that the heights are dynamic, but I always want to use the first column's height)

Is this possible with pure css? or do I have to use javascript to accomplish this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Sure, why not just limit the height using a special CSS class like this..

```
.row.limit [class*="col-"]{
  max-height:50px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

http://bootply.com/3LIJcG0SBe

If you don't need to apply the class to *all* Bootstrap columns (col-*) it would be better to apply a specific CSS selector. Then add `limit` to the approprite columns...

```
.limit {
  max-height:50px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: The height of the column is dynamic. Sorry if it was unclear from the original question!

Comment: You can use data attributes for your dinamic CSS.
Take a look into this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes